# Не получается натренировать нейронную сеть

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, numpy

Народ, всем привет! Столкнулся с бедой - нужно натренировать сеть по приложенному датасету (выше) и образцу с хабра ([сам пост](https://habr.com/post/271563/)). Итоговый результат никак не похож на изначальный набор значений. С чем я мог налажать: грешу на сигмоиду, но упустить что-то важное из внимания мог и в любом другом месте. Огромное спасибо, если откликнитесь!

[Описание сета](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/heart+Disease)

[Данные](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/heart-disease/processed.cleveland.data)

(Предварительно удалил строчки с вопросительными знаками и поместил сет в txt).

[По-английски/in English](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53805154)

```
import numpy as np

# sigmoid func
def sigmoid(x, deriv=False):
    if deriv:
        # print(sigmoid(x) * (1 - sigmoid(x)))
        return sigmoid(x) * (1 - sigmoid(x))
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))


# input initialization
dataset = np.genfromtxt('dataset.txt', delimiter=',')
X = dataset[..., 0:12]
y = np.array([dataset[..., 13]]).T

# input normalization
Xn = X / X.max(axis=0)
yn = y / y.max(axis=0)

# random numbers initialization
np.random.seed(1)
syn0 = 2 * np.random.random((12, 1)) - 1

for i in range(50000):
    # direct error propagation
    l0 = Xn
    l1 = sigmoid(np.dot(l0, syn0))
    # error computing
    l1_error = yn - l1
    # multiply this by the slope of sigmoid
    # using values of l1
    l1_delta = l1_error * sigmoid(l1, True) # - !
    # weights update
    syn0 += np.dot(l0.T, l1_delta)  # - !
print("Output data after training: ")
print(l1)

Actual result        Required result:      
[[8.25305827e-28]    ~0
 [9.99999908e-01]    ~0.5
 [5.25318843e-04]    ~0.25
 [2.41309677e-22]    ~0
 [2.09811612e-28]    ~0
 [2.37186828e-34]    ~0
 [1.43044972e-07]    ~0.75
 [6.83698176e-30]    ~0
...                  ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Дело в том, что это датасет для мультиклассовой классификации: y принимает значения 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. Для решения такой задачи нужна другая функция активации (softmax обычно) и другая функция потерь (обычно crossentropy). Советую взять датасет с бинарным таргетом.

Comment: Андрей, благодарю Вас за ответ, основная проблема и состоит в том, что условие сдачи задания - использование этого сета, тогда хотелось бы поинтересоваться: есть ли гайды с подобным приложенному материалу в плане качетва и доступности подачи материала; язык не принципиален (разве что не диалекты новозеландских аборигенов :) ). Прошурстив сеть, нашел несколько, но боюсь не осилить в обозримом будущем. Вновь благодарю за оказанную поддержку!

Comment: http://www.wildml.com/2015/09/implementing-a-neural-network-from-scratch/ https://stackabuse.com/creating-a-neural-network-from-scratch-in-python-multi-class-classification/ Думаю можно попробовать эти 2 статьи.